# Send DateTime in Post Request

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

Hi I have C# (Xamarin) app and .net API. How can I post a DateTime to my .Net API?

The .Net API

At the moment I have:

```
        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Email", u.Email),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", u.Password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ConfirmPassword", u.ConfirmPassword),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Gender", u.Gender),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DateOfBirth", u.DateOfBirth)
        });


        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/api/Account/Register", formContent);
```

The strings all work fine, however I can't figure out the DateTime one. I would have guessed it to be:

```
       KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>("DateOfBirth", u.DateOfBirth)
```

but that does not work. If I convert the DateTime to a string, the date on the server just comes through as 01/01/1900 which isn't right either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up serialising the object which had all the all the attributes I wanted to post and this seemed to work.

```
string postBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(u);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/api/Account/Register", new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

Answer (score 1):

What about sending the ticks?

Convert the `DataTime` to ticks and send them:

```
var ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
```

Comment: Also it may be worth to use DateTime.UtcNow instead of just ".Now" because you never can be sure that server and client are on the same time zone, geographically or configurationally.

Comment: @YurySchkatula , right, I actually just chose a random value of `DataTime` (which was `Now`) to show the usage of `Ticks` Property. But in productive way, sure that `UtcNow` is the reliable way.

Comment: I like this solution.  It makes everything very simple to do.